# How can we redirect system calls between OSes?

Tags: operating-system, system-calls, distributed-computing

I am trying to transfer the computational load of a single process between multiple PCs, instruction wise. I want to intercept system calls and divert between multiple PCs to reduce computational time. I want to capture the system call before the host OS and decide whether the call need to be handled by the host or transferred to another PC.

Is there any efficient way to do this? please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn’t sound rational to do such a thing at “system call” level in any way. So most likely no, there is no efficient way to do such a thing.

Comment: Different OSes might have different system calls. Can you handle that? Besides that, after returning a system call, your processor state needs to be revoked again. Do you handle this as well?

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh Redirection between similar OSes, like windows to windows (but between different PC's). Are you asking about revocation of privileges?

Comment: if you're just looking to distribute load, then the syscall boundary is not the right one - you need to fine boundaries where it make sense to parallelize and use regular RPCs (or just execute the same program with different args via ssh) on the other compute node.